# How to handle incorrect overriding of standard functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I develop a JavaScript module to prevent basic dom-based XSS on a client-side. I use a couple of standard functions: indexOf(), substring(), toString(), etc. 
During a testing I found that some external JavaScript libraries sometimes can incorrectly override functions. For example, [the following overriding of indexOf() function](http://tomck.homecredit.ru/bitrix/cache/js/s1/main/template_bd51dacf7d7d7fe68618a06ec7aff9f1/template_bd51dacf7d7d7fe68618a06ec7aff9f1_a295896371b727f08ee2af7f50148ac9.js?1455569053638565) does not return -1 if an element is not present in the array:

```
; /* Start:/js/jquery.select.js*/
(function($){

//add class of js to html tag
$('html').addClass('js');

//create cross-browser indexOf
Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, start) {
    for (var i = (start || 0); i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == obj) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

So this new `indexOf()` can break `ifStatement`. The trivial example:

`function protect(s){
    ...
    if(sNodes.indexOf(node) !== -1) { {
       /*injection found*/
       sanitize(s); 
    ...
    }
}`

Now `indexOf()` returns `undefined` if node is not present. In my case this can lead to false positive and sanitization of correct input data.
The script must be executed before and after DOMContentLoaded.
One note: I can not control environment where my. script will be used for sanitizing. It somethins like WAF and shoul work with any JavaScript application

My suggestions are the following:

1. Implement own versions of main critical functions (e.g., [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf))
2. Save references to these function before they will be overrided and the use them:
   `Array.prototype._indexOf = Array.prototype._indexOf;
   ...
   function sanitize(s){
       ...
       if(sNodes.indexOf(node) !== -1) { {
          /*injection found*/
          sanitize(s); 
       ...
       }
   }`

Are they correct?
What are the best practices to deal with this issue?

Comment: Is requirement to check if string contains a specific character ?

Comment: Your plan seems like it would work, except that you shouldn't test against specific cases. You should just make sure that you override it yourself in case someone also overrides (the function is not the same as the original, which you must save before any other code is parsed). By the way, don't use that library that overrides indexOf. If they are that careless shimming `indexOf`, imagine the rest of the lib

Comment: I agree with what @JuanMendes said. Don't use a library that polyfills methods incorrectly. The ECMA-262 standard exists for a reason.

Comment: In this instance, I would attempt a quick fix of the library and send the creators a note suggesting they do the same. If patching causes the library to throw errors, use a different library as Juan suggested.

Comment: I can not control libraries that web applications use. My script is something like client-side Web Application Firewall and it should work with any JavaScript libraries.

Comment: @alpha A "client-side Web Application Firewall" isn't going to work in 100% of the cases. It will always be possible to override or disable it. This is one of these cases. Don't try to fight it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are my suggestions correct?

Yes. For solution 2, you might want to use `var indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf` and then `indexOf.call(sNodes, node)` (if you trust that `Function.prototype.call` hasn't been messed with…) to avoid creating methods on builtin prototypes. And of course you need to ensure that your library is loaded before the malicious one.

> What are the best practices to deal with this issue?

Ignore the issue. Write your code as you'd always do.

If you find another library that does such shit, a) file a bug with them and b) replace it with a better one. If anyone insists on using such a library, charge them extra.

If your actual goal is to prevent such issues entirely, use [Caja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caja_project).